# Can an HTML element be both displayed and ignored?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to draw SVG lines over HTML elements, while:

1. The lines should be above the elements.
2. The elements should be clickable and selectable, meaning, the SVG does not cover the elements in terms of being able to click or select them.

As the `z-index` of lines cannot be configured separately from the `z-index` of the SVG (from what I know), the only way I thought about is to give the SVG a high `z-index` but set it to be ignored in terms of disrupting the elements beneath.

Is this possible?

Any other ideas how to implement the lines over elements without disrupting the ability to click and select them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add following css to SVG lines.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: Amazingly simple and perfect. Seems to be working awesome. THANKS!

Comment: Yeah +1 for this solution (and you should accept this @TomerHadad!). But please be advised that older browsers don't support it (see [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)). Bear this in mind if you have agreed browser compatibility with your client. Otherwise you should write a little javascript that passes down the click event.